# Can I have an account in Windows 10 that is linked to my MS account but does not use a password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, user-accounts

I have a Windows 10 PC in my living that I use as a media PC. Originally I installed Windows 10 and set up a local account without a password. I want this because several people use this PC and I don't want to tell them my account password (and I don't want any password on there at all for ease of use).

I went to install the Netflix metro app from the windows app store and it asked me to log in using my MS credentials. I did this and it immediately linked the user account to my MS account. Now I have to enter my password at the login screen of the PC. Is there any way to have a user account that is linked to my MS account but does not have a password? Ideally I would like to have a single account on this PC without a password (so there is no logon screen at startup, it just goes straight to the desktop).

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I have no time to write up a proper answer. Yes, you can configure Win10 to automatically sign in. Everything you need to know, including step-by-step instructions, is here: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10/

Comment: __But__ keep in mind that if you do so everybody with access to the machine will have full access to your MS account, can send emails pretending to be you, open accounts and confirm them with your email address, etc., best have guest access for media use and a password for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to achieve this. The first suggestion is probably the best one.

## 1. Convert your account back to a local account

You need to have a live account to be able to download apps from the windows store, but when you don't use it, you don't actually have to keep using your live account. So my suggestion is to convert it back to a local account. This can be done through `start`->`Settings`->`Accounts`.

### 2. Use auto-login

Alternatively, you can make windows automatically login to windows using your account details. Do note that by doing so, your password will be stored in the registry. Changing your account password may be a good idea.

Start a command prompt with administrative privileges, and run `netplwiz`
At the top uncheck `[ ] Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`. Hit OK and use valid login credentials.

Do note that even though the pc will now automatically log in, if someone locks the screen (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) someone will have to enter the password.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate problem of someone locking the screen when PC set to auto logon.

1. Set the PC to use a PIN to logon
2. Put a sticker on PC with PIN written on it

Not perfect but doesn't expose account password.